# Cannot launch chromium after build for mac

Tags: google-chrome, build, chromium

Trying to launch Chromium on mac x86_64 and i got an error:

```
[22.04.2023 14:27]
Last login: Sat Apr 22 15:06:16 on ttys002
zzaghaev@MacBook-Pro-ZZ ~ % /Users/zzaghaev/Downloads/Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium ; exit;
[27326:259:0422/152703.542796:ERROR:chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(162)] Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled.
[27326:259:0422/152704.409348:FATAL:ax_range.h(134)] Check failed: second->IsValid(). 
0   Chromium Framework                  0x0000000131987f62 base::debug::CollectStackTrace(void**, unsigned long) + 18
1   Chromium Framework                  0x0000000131973ef3 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace() + 19
2   Chromium Framework                  0x00000001318343d5 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage() + 181
3   Chromium Framework                  0x000000013181c290 logging::(anonymous namespace)::DCheckLogMessage::~DCheckLogMessage() + 48
4   Chromium Framework                  0x000000013181bf77 logging::CheckError::~CheckError() + 23
5   Chromium Framework                  0x000000013181bf99 logging::CheckError::~CheckError() + 9
6   Chromium Framework                  0x000000012f557ae6 ui::AXRange<ui::AXPosition<ui::AXNodePosition, ui::AXNode>>::CompareEndpoints(ui::AXPosition<ui::AXNodePosition, ui::AXNode> const*, ui::AXPosition<ui::AXNodePosition, ui::AXNode> const*) + 294
7   Chromium Framework                  0x000000012f54c375 ui::AXRange<ui::AXPosition<ui::AXNodePosition, ui::AXNode>>::AsForwardRange() const + 53
8   Chromium Framework                  0x0000000133d9d9c0 ui::AXRange<ui::AXPosition<ui::AXNodePosition, ui::AXNode>>::begin() const + 80
9   Chromium Framework                  0x0000000133d9c627 -[AXPlatformNodeCocoa addTextAnnotationsIn:to:] + 87
10  Chromium Framework                  0x0000000133da2582 -[AXPlatformNodeCocoa AXAttributedStringForRange:] + 418
11  AppKit                              0x00007ff8182da3a5 -[NSAccessibilityAttributeAccessorInfo getParameterizedAttributeValue:forObject:withParameter:] + 65
12  AppKit                              0x00007ff8182dc219 ___NSAccessibilityEntryPointValueForAttributeWithParameter_block_invoke.879 + 447
13  AppKit                              0x00007ff8182d6f83 NSAccessibilityPerformEntryPointObject + 16
14  AppKit                              0x00007ff8182d8b5b NSAccessibilityEntryPointValueForAttributeWithParameter + 172
15  AppKit                              0x00007ff81808723c CopyParameterizedAttributeValue + 485
16  HIServices                          0x00007ff81a3932bc _AXXMIGCopyParameterizedAttributeValue + 495
17  HIServices                          0x00007ff81a3b6daa _XCopyParameterizedAttributeValue + 627
18  HIServices                          0x00007ff81a3735a9 mshMIGPerform + 182
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff814b4a0b1 CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION + 41
20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff814b49fee __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 540
21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff814b48c6b __CFRunLoopRun + 2705
22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff814b47b60 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
23  HIToolbox                           0x00007ff81e495766 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
24  HIToolbox                           0x00007ff81e495576 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 679
25  HIToolbox                           0x00007ff81e4952b3 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 70
26  AppKit                              0x00007ff817c982f3 _DPSNextEvent + 909
27  AppKit                              0x00007ff817c97174 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1219
28  Chromium Framework                  0x00000001310e7490 __71-[BrowserCrApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]_block_invoke + 64
29  Chromium Framework                  0x00000001319abef2 base::mac::CallWithEHFrame(void () block_pointer) + 10
30  Chromium Framework                  0x00000001310e7409 -[BrowserCrApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 153
31  AppKit                              0x00007ff817c897b7 -[NSApplication run] + 586

Mihail Titkov, [22.04.2023 14:27]
32  Chromium Framework                  0x00000001319b1c7c base::MessagePumpNSApplication::DoRun(base::MessagePump::Delegate*) + 300
33  Chromium Framework                  0x00000001319afedf base::MessagePumpCFRunLoopBase::Run(base::MessagePump::Delegate*) + 111
34  Chromium Framework                  0x00000001318fb7f9 base::sequence_manager::internal::ThreadControllerWithMessagePumpImpl::Run(bool, base::TimeDelta) + 505
35  Chromium Framework                  0x0000000131898b59 base::RunLoop::Run(base::Location const&) + 713
36  Chromium Framework                  0x000000012eaa7bfd content::BrowserMainLoop::RunMainMessageLoop() + 141
37  Chromium Framework                  0x000000012eaaa1c5 content::BrowserMainRunnerImpl::Run() + 37
38  Chromium Framework                  0x000000012eaa3f56 content::BrowserMain(content::MainFunctionParams) + 134
39  Chromium Framework                  0x0000000130909814 content::RunBrowserProcessMain(content::MainFunctionParams, content::ContentMainDelegate*) + 212
40  Chromium Framework                  0x000000013090ba25 content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::RunBrowser(content::MainFunctionParams, bool) + 1429
41  Chromium Framework                  0x000000013090b2e5 content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Run() + 1285
42  Chromium Framework                  0x0000000130908f82 content::RunContentProcess(content::ContentMainParams, content::ContentMainRunner*) + 1586
43  Chromium Framework                  0x0000000130909197 content::ContentMain(content::ContentMainParams) + 103
44  Chromium Framework                  0x000000012b0bf8c0 ChromeMain + 560
45  Chromium                            0x000000010c49187e main + 286
46  dyld                                0x00007ff81473b310 start + 2432
Crash keys:
  "ax_mode" = "kNativeAPIs | kWebContents | kInlineTextBoxes | kScreenReader | "
  "ui_scheduler_async_stack" = "0x132766777 0x0"
  "gpu-glver" = "OpenGL ES 2.0.0 (ANGLE 2.1.1 git hash: 23ec06204174)"
  "gpu-generation-intel" = "9"
  "gpu-vsver" = "1.00"
  "gpu-psver" = "1.00"
  "gpu-driver" = "20.2.50"
  "gpu_count" = "1"
  "gpu-devid" = "0x3ea6"
  "gpu-venid" = "0x8086"
  "num-extensions" = "0"
  "breadcrumbs" = "0:00:00 Tab1 PageLoad
0:00:00 Tab1 FinishNav2
0:00:00 Tab1 StartNav2 #renderer-script #auto_subframe
0:00:00 Tab1 FinishNav1
0:00:00 Tab1 AddInfobar44
0:00:00 Tab1 AddInfobar45
0:00:00 Browser1 Insert active Tab1 at 0
0:00:00 Tab1 StartNav1 #ntp #auto_toplevel
0:00:00 Startup
"
  "io_scheduler_async_stack" = "0x132766777 0x0"
  "amfi-status" = "rv=0 status=0x0 allow_everything=0"
  "reentry_guard_tls_slot" = "262"

"variations" = "db59f83a-3f4a17df,8bccc03b-3f4a17df,e45cd2f5-ace4e138,da493d3c-3f4a17df,2510663e-73703436,d5a65352-3f4a17df,4810967e-3f4a17df,9f476f76-3f4a17df,f3ed486d-3f4a17df,5c783e42-8f8fa88f,36d5ee52-3f4a17df,65570806-377be55a,8659ca17-3f4a17df,ade3efeb-e1cc0f14,179d29a7-3f4a17df,3fd33f16-27b09c4c,3095b8fe-3f4a17df,3f9314a8-3f4a17df,4ff8f5b5-9c1f9d3b,e1adfff5-3f4a17df,5f36436a-f799c15e,87a22c16-5123f057,baee3c29-3f4a17df,9fe21c85-3f4a17df,78aca32-3f4a17df,250dda8b-3f4a17df,5be458ba-78266b16,47be28a0-3f4a17df,ef4764d7-c9f4d4ef,a779bb20-3f4a17df,f0682056-324bfab2,2da2abac-b7f59038,d3566fbd-c6f74b94,3e6ca8ad-3f4a17df,741e95d4-3f4a17df,520b2a89-88bf9f37,c4e32a07-3a3251a9,5851a53a-8897814c,1d0518a-3f4a17df,e7887996-cb1364b6,42f1f10d-98837767,ad4acdda-3f4a17df,7fb629a1-60fdb59,90860314-3f4a17df,d6284ba0-3be74c4d,de2c80ca-da5d16c4,6ad21bf6-d47270c,ca12356a-ee1c2cee,28410024-3f4a17df,b1ceb06f-3f4a17df,d2e8e6e4-3f4a17df,73a2859d-b607c060,8c82550d-3f4a17df,9909b8ac-3f4a17df,933702bb-3f4a17df,a2fd384c-cc71bb94,1fce7d57-3f4a17df,90fa3bb1-3f4a17df,e8c68789-49a20295,d990c4ac-3f4a17df,e0e63e5f-decb98bf,edddf950-49eb759f,911e33b9-3f4a17df,19d422be-c9846617,201e98ca-53757ab,5c7c8339-3f4a17df,e521d2ef-3f4a17df,7ec047c2-3f4a17df,ec21b181-3f4a17df,53c131d9-e3ef03f6,4d936449-fd549ada,9e5c75f1-30e1b12b,83a09cba-fcf6c09,9a24c3c2-7656653c,1acce950-3f4a17df,eddd0d82-3f4a17df,99c32967-f0a9a61e,4749874c-455e925b,824b2e8d-6b54c43,caa76e48-caa76e48,26db9e79-f430c221,b0f15b33-b0f15b33,7760b5b2-3f4a17df,5c4d440e-58c8ac88,de95f00f-3f4a17df,f112d133-3f4a17df,75ffb03a-3f4a17df,78634d5f-2ba5dc1c,fcad39d1-3f4a17df,a7780b9-3f4a17df,cd59be9a-6e5c8f84,c80a7778-85a1d8e4,b16eab85-95ab9b79,e52d4c86-3f4a17df,a8cfdb40-3f4a17df,e3fd1192-3f4a17df,f8b7087b-3d47f4f4,13427e22-3f4a17df,1d167f26-3f4a17df,8d7344de-3f4a17df,910af27f-3f4a17df,7a842d4a-b3a17800,50eaf59c-3f4a17df,f2855e3d-de2b6078,74235cf4-3f4a17df,17cd3426-3f4a17df,77b7ea96-9a159164,1bb6a450-3f4a17df,3e99ae8f-21e7ece7,b349dbf8-3f4a17df,5be633d-3f4a17df,870c1db8-3f4a17df,f14c322f-f9a43703,263848e4-3f4a17df,ae850472-3f4a17df,9982045c-3f4a17df,95bc6922-3f4a17df,cf64b238-3f4a17df,a79ba57a-f23d1dea,ea23a088-41c37e8a,4949c1d8-3f4a17df,371f259c-3f4a17df,b46f46d-3f4a17df,e11c0dd9-3586c521,f6e27768-f695fd79,3b96a1d-3f4a17df,6becb1e-a6ea97a2,595f5eb0-f23d1dea,f73d1d52-3f4a17df,d92d97b4-e913bec6,94f1fa38-66264bee,d7d493f4-a9412e3f,565dffc5-565dffc5,15d3083e-5ce60213,9a564e2a-3f4a17df,d664a1aa-3f4a17df,31af02a2-3f4a17df,87f33ad6-3f4a17df,fd051c38-3f4a17df,42f0e0ea-75d6947c,160d8d8d-9d12ca0c,4ea303a6-3f4a17df,3042ad4b-ad2fa222,b3c54bb3-a058b5d3,f654ad46-c94f66c2,cbc04857-3f4a17df,1584cf60-3f4a17df,bbaef9b4-3f4a17df,55ba4cfa-3f4a17df,504f455d-3f4a17df,c297985a-3f4a17df,8963b549-3f4a17df,3e7d7783-a4655118,18324944-3f4a17df,81b1a2c3-3f4a17df,186d6e2c-36c0e608,26016f9f-4df4f25e,9ee43808-3f4a17df,8ddeb5cd-3f4a17df,ee9c60c1-20131bcc,b357b792-3f4a17df,9481ce98-3d47f4f4,4b935545-3d47f4f4,be338734-dee66fa8,70678518-dee66fa8,5f9907a9-dee66fa8,8eeccb9a-dee66fa8,2b465683-dee66fa8,9a38bae3-3d47f4f4,c9af35af-ec47f63d,2d1e43a3-3d47f4f4,b0455224-417b7a1e,d4e31d2-417b7a1e,d69d967d-3695c92e,"
  "num-experiments" = "174"
  "num-switches" = "2"
  "osarch" = "x86_64"
  "pid" = "27326"
  "ptype" = "browser"

[0422/152704.780882:WARNING:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(235)] UniversalExceptionRaise: (os/kern) failure (5)
zsh: trace trap  /Users/zzaghaev/Downloads/Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

I was trying to launch Cromium with many args something like `--remote-allow-origins=*`, `--disable-extensions`, `--allow_unknown_root_cer --disable_certificate_verification` and so on...
How to fix it? The Chromium i was build by my self and its work perfect on my mac pc and on my friend mac, but its not working on another my friend mac, in his mac book we got this error.

Comment: How is this related to C?

Comment: @haris Chromium writen on cc and c langs. If u can see error above the errors was in cc files. Thats why i was add c and c++ tags, maybe any one can watch error lines in github chromium code and explain me how to fix it.

Comment: Please add args.gn to the question.